# Proving the Fibonacci Identity $\sum_{i=1}^{2n} f_{i-1}\cdot f_i=f_{2n}^2$ using induction

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

I've proven the base case, and my induction hypothesis reads

(IH) for $k\geq 1$, $\sum_{i=1}^{2k} f_{i-1}\cdot f_i=f_{2k}^2$

Now, we want to show that

$\sum_{i=1}^{2(k+1)} f_{i-1}\cdot f_i=f_{2(k+1)}^2$

My induction step begins with considering $n=k+1$, then

$\sum_{i=1}^{2(k+1)} f_{i-1}\cdot f_i=\sum_{i=1}^{2k} f_{i-1}\cdot f_i+(f_{(k+1)-1}\cdot f_{k+1})+(f_{(k+2)-1}\cdot f_{k+2})$

$\hspace{3.25cm}=f_{2k}^2+(f_{k}\cdot f_{k+1})+(f_{k+1}\cdot f_{k+2})$

From here I've tried every manipulation I can think of to try and make this come out to

$f_{2(k+1)}^2$

but everything just leads me back to where I started, or leads nowhere. I'm completely stumped and out of ideas for how to continue.

EDIT:

Thanks to John Omielan, I was able to find a silly error, but I am still stuck.

The proper induction step should be

$\sum_{i=1}^{2(k+1)} f_{i-1}\cdot f_i=\sum_{i=1}^{2k} f_{i-1}\cdot f_i+(f_{(2k+1)-1}\cdot f_{2k+1})+(f_{(2k+2)-1}\cdot f_{2k+2})$

$\hspace{3.25cm}=f_{2k}^2+(f_{2k}\cdot f_{2k+1})+(f_{2k+1}\cdot f_{2k+2})$

Some quick manipulation gives

$\hspace{3.25cm}=f_{2k}^2+(f_{2k}\cdot f_{2k+1})+(f_{2k+1}\cdot(f_{2k}+ f_{2k+1}))$

$\hspace{3.25cm}=f_{2k}^2+2f_{2k}\cdot f_{2k+1}+f_{2k+1}^2$

but after this is where, again, I start going in circles. I'm just not seeing the proper manipulation. Expanding out some of these terms just has me accumulating $f_{2k}\cdot f_{2k+1}$ terms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fibonacci Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285985/fibonacci-proof) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7B2k%7D%20f_%7Bi-1%7D%5Ccdot%20f_i%3Df_%7B2k%7D%5E2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainduction&p=1).

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, there's also the quite similar [How to prove this Fibonacci Statement?](/q/2690263/602049).

Comment: Thanks John! I was able to find an error in my induction step, but I'm still having issues. I've updated my question.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that $f_{2k+2} = f_{2k} + f_{2k+1}$ by how Fibonacci numbers are defined. Thus, using that $(x + y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$, we get that $f_{2k+2}^2 = (f_{2k} + f_{2k+1})^2 = f_{2k}^2 + 2f_{2k}f_{2k+1} + f_{2k+1}^2$, i.e., the current final equation line in your question. This is what you're trying to prove in your inductive step since $f_{2(k+1)}^2 = f_{2k+2}^2$.

Comment: Wow. I don't know if I would have ever noticed that. I'm very new to this type of math. Thanks so much for your help.